# Add a reverse of a typewriter effect?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have this animation wait for 2 seconds and then reverse itself? (typewriter effect) I found this online and have edited it slightly but I'm still learning (very early stages). is this possible within CSS, HTML and javascript? I'm going to use this as an alert for my twitch stream.

CSS:

```css
@import url('https://cdn.streamelements.com/scripts/animate.min.css');
/* GLOBAL STYLES */
body {
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 100%}
  to { width: 0}
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: white }
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="typewriter">
    <h1>
        <span id="username-container"></span>
        is now following.
    </h1>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code and I put the animation on an infinite loop. You can modify the code below to suit your needs and requirements. The main point below are the `animation` and `KeyFrame`. The code sample also has the reverse typewriter effect.

```css
.typewriter-text1 {
  animation-name: typewriter1;
}



.typewriter-text1{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(25, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.typewriter-text1::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  animation: caret infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes typewriter1 {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  10%,
  40% {
    width: 17em;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
<h1>
  <span class="typewriter-text1">
    is now following.
  </span>
 
</h1>
<div class="typewriter">
```